# How to programmatically access Mongoid's config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, mongoid

Specifically, I want to read the `hosts` value of the current Mongoid config.
Is that possible?

I'm using Mongoid with Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the following:

```
config = YAML::load(File.read(Rails.root.join('config/mongoid.yml')))
```

this give you the following output

```
{"development"=>
  {"sessions"=>
    {"default"=>
      {"database"=>"analytics_new_development",
       "hosts"=>["localhost:27017"],
       "options"=>nil}},
   "options"=>{"raise_not_found_error"=>false}},
 "test"=>
  {"sessions"=>
    {"default"=>
      {"database"=>"mongodemo_test",
       "hosts"=>["localhost:27017"],
       "options"=>
        {"consistency"=>:strong, "max_retries"=>1, "retry_interval"=>0}}}},
 "production"=>
  {"sessions"=>
    {"default"=>
      {"database"=>"analytics_aws_production",
       "hosts"=>["180.149.246.126"],
       "options"=>nil}},
   "options"=>{"raise_not_found_error"=>false}}}
```

Using the above hash you can take out the desired values that you need.

Comment: Thanks. Ideally, it should work in all cases, even when the config is set dynamically.

Comment: please accept this answer if this solved your problem

Comment: I'm going to wait and see if there are other answers that work in all cases. Don't hesitate to remind me if I forget to pick an answer!